# Get smallest possible composite primary key (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, composite-primary-key

I was wondering if there is an easy solution to get the smallest possible composite primary key. First i want to describe the database structure that i want to use:

```
Table 1: Account
accountId serial PRIMARY KEY
username text

Table 2: Email
accountId FOREIGN KEY
accountEmailId tinyint
email text
(accountId, accountEmailId) PRIMARY KEY
```

The database structure should provide the possibilty that an account has multiple email addresses (limited to tinyint numbers). I wanted to use this architecture because it doen't use that much space in the table compared to what i call a 'standard' design:

```
Table 2: Email
emailId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
accountId FOREIGN KEY
email text
```

I don't need to make a request directly (WHERE emailId = ..) based on the emailId, because i always want to make sure the email address is linked to a certain account. So for me it's always necessary to check for the accountId as well: (WHERE emailId = .. AND accountId = ..). That means i don't need the emaildId to be unique. Because i build a composite primary key of the accountId and the accountEmailId, the accountEmailId itself can be a tinyint. Both the together build a nice unique identifier.

My question are: Is this a good database architecture or should i stick to the 'standard' one (OR use an array field for all email addresses)? Is there a way to automatically set the accountEmailId based on the already in-use accountEmailId?

For example:

```
Record 1:
accountId **23**
accountEmailId **1**
email mail@example.com

Record 2:
accountId **23**
accountEmailId **2**
email mail2@example.com

Record 3:
accountId **18**
accountEmailId **1**
email mail2@example.com
```

The next record for accountId 23 should be:

```
accountId 23
accountEmailId 3
email mail2@example.com
```

and so on..

Comment: The design of database tables should be drive both by their contents and how the data will be used.  You have really clarified the latter point.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with yor design, if saving two bytes per table row is your top priority.

But two bytes is very little, and you'd have to take care with defining your table, else you can easily lose the two bytes (and more) to *padding*, because many data types are aligned at four- or eight-byte boundaries.

The biggest drawback I can see is that you cannot fill the `emailaccountid` automatically – you have to get all emails already defined for that account to find a free number. Alternatively, you could “blindly” insert values, catch primary key violations and retry with a different value. Both don't seem very appealing.

I personally would not care about wasting two bytes.